# allowing users to key in multiple lines in command prompt by using C

Tags: c

I don't really know about C. So, my questions and ideas may be misleading or ridiculous or embarrassing. Please forgive me..

The question states that the program should get the user input from the command prompt. the input text will have numbers, alphabets and space characters. they will have multiple lines too..

The example program is using `<stdio.h>` and hence `printf` and `scanf`.

Using `cin` and `cout` is not encouraged according to the textbook. In order to use `cin` and `cout`, I need `<iostream>` but I can't `include` `<iostream>`. Even if I could include `<iostream>`, but I then can't `include` `<stdio.h>` anymore.

I also can't use `string`. I've heard that `C` doesn't allow the use of `string`, but I don't really understand why.

---

My question is; when you ask users to type in something with `printf("Enter your text: ");`, they can only type in one line.. once they hit `Enter`, the program receive it.

Is there anyway to use `scanf` to allow users to type in multiple lines by typing `Shift+Enter` for example.

As `string` is not available, should I use a `char` array like `char inputText[999]`? Will this give me enough space?

My two questions are; How to allow users to type multiple lines in command prompt, and what data type should I use to save the entered text?

I googled it but they mix C++ and C..

Thanks to all and once again, i apologize if my question is a waste of time for you..

Hi all, I have done it.. but I only have one more problem..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int nc=0,nw=0,bs=0,c, nq=0, nl=0;
int main()
{
    printf("Text Analysis Program\n\n");
    printf("Enter your text:");
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if( (c>='A' && c<='Z') || (c>='a' &&  c<='z') )
        {
            nc++;
        }
        else if( c>='0' && c<='9' )
        {
            nq++;
        }
        else if (c==' ')
        {
            nw++;
            bs++;       
        }
        else if (c=='\n')
        {
            nw++;
            nl++;
        }
    }
    printf("Number of characters: %d;\n",nc);
    printf("Number of words: %d;\n",nw);
    printf("Number of numerical quantities: %d;\n",nq);
    printf("Number of blank spaces: %d;\n",bs);
    printf("Number of lines entered: %d;\n",nl);
    exit(0);
}
```

At the end, after the answers are shown, `cmd` screen closes straight away.. I removed `exit(0)` it is still the same. Is there any commands to freeze the screen and appears `Press any key to continue`

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you; you need to show what you've tried so far and explain how it didn't work as you expected. We can help you figure out what went wrong. If we do it for you, you won't learn anything, and some of us may end up trying to fix things you work on in the future. :) Please edit your post to provide the above, and someone here will be happy to try and help you. Hint: You can call `scanf` in a loop until it gets nothing but a newline ('\n').

Comment: Ok.. the code is at home.. now i m at work.. so, i will reply when i get home.. thks..

Comment: If your program is to be C, you cannot use `<iostream>` or `cin` or `cout`; those are C++ facilities.

Comment: For character classification, you should use the macros such as `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` from `#include <ctype.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `getchar()` call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Press any key to continue. ");
  fflush(stdout);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

It actually doesn't return until you type a full line or it hits EOF but it should be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

These:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
cin
cout
```

are C++-specific.  They simply don't exist in C.  Remember that C and C++ are two different languages.

The fact that your window is closing when the program terminates is a function of the development system you're using.  If you run the program from a command prompt, that won't happen -- or there may be an option in your IDE to tell it to keep the window open until you close it explicitly.  But if you don't want to do that, J.F. Sebastian's solution is a good one.

Another hint: take a look at the `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` functions in `<ctype.h>`.